# A windows phone store issue?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have Developed an WP8 App and submitted it in the WP8 store ,my problem is when i downloaded my App from the store the app is not functioning.It crashes when I open my App .I tested the XAP file in the Emulator and in the device it works fine before submitting it in the store.Please Help me if u have any suggestion for my problem.

Comment: You'd have to provide much more information. Any error messages anywhere?

Comment: Or you could follow the guideline mentioned here :- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/windows-8-apps-not-opening-and-windows-store/d97238b3-033b-412d-ba58-58aa32e3cc77

Comment: It doesn't give any error message but it crashes when the splash screen appears.

Comment: there could me many reasons why you app crashed...for example not using try catch or other conditions statements to check whether location is enabled or disabled in the phone before using it.